# Ensuring Updated CSS/JavaScript on Client Side

Tags: javascript, css, caching

I'm trying to ensure that visitors of my ASP.NET MVC website always have the most-current CSS and Javascript (and not some older cached version).

I tried to realize this by generating a seed value when the application domain starts, and automatically append it to the CSS and Javascript URLs (so now instead of /Content/All.js the link is /Content/All.js?549238 etc.).

Unfortunately I just found out by debugging via Firebug that this causes now a full download request *every* time (the new "seeded" response is no longer cached *at all*, but I only wanted the first check to download the 'updated' version, but then cache again/only check if there is a difference).

How can I achieve my goal, is there a better way of doing this? I need the client to always request the newest version, but then cache if no change happened.

**Edit: This appears to be related to the fact that my page is served over SSL.** I  [asked a follow up question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448065/ssl-problem-client-side-caching-js-css) regarding enabling clientside caching with SSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the seed value you are generating is a random number. Replace this with  a version number so that it will be re downloaded only when the version number of your application changes.

Like

/Content/All.js?appVer1.5

and when you modify the application you can change that to something like

/Content/All.js?appVer1.6

Comment: It's not random. As I stated it's generated once as a static readonly when the application domain is initializing. Can't be written or changed more than exactly one single time for the entire lifetime of the w3wp process.

Comment: Accepted even though it didn't really answer my question... best/first though of the field.

Answer (score 1):

Put the revision number in the url: `foo.css?rev=348`

-- Edit

You can achieve this pretty trivially as well, using your build tool (I actually do it with a custom thing I've written).

-- Edit

And if it floats your boat, this is what SO does.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a checksum of the file's content as the number, like `All-a2a69e19d8628b65cb935708d64d7337.js`. This way the number only changes when the contents of the script changes.
2. Create some mechanism that is responsible for generating the link and/or `<script>` tag to the JavaScript file.

This way, in your ASP.NET page, have something like:

```
<asp:ScriptTag source="All.js"/>
```

Which gets replaced by:

```
<script src="/All-a2a69e19d8628b65cb935708d64d7337.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: This is a little ridiculous. Why not just use the last modified date, if you're going to do with a scheme like this?

Comment: Because, to identify changes in the file, the modification time of the file is less accurate than its contents?

Comment: I don't think accuracy is a big matter in this situation.

Comment: No, the modification time will be quite accurate, unless you decide to programmatically change it to be back in time. Either way, it's not a good idea when it's so trivial to include the build number. Specially given you suggest changing the filename, which isn't required.